# Comboboxes from bash

Tags: command-line, input, user-interface

I want a combobox from the shell. That is, a dropdown of default items with some fuzzy searching and, importantly, **the ability to enter a value that is not in the list**.

In gui environments, this is supported by tools like `rofi`: 
`cat options | rofi -dmenu` does precisely what I need, with `C-ENTER` forcing an option not in the list.

Is there an equivalent of this which is pure command-line? [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) seems like the closest analogue in the pure command line space, but a brief review of its manual page suggests there is no suitable binding for "accept the text as entered".

**Workarounds**

There are of course workarounds

- Use a menu system with number indexing including an entry for "create new"
- The same but within `fzf`

But neither of these are easy as they could be.

Comment: I think `dialog` can do this.

Comment: Hmm... I couldn't find what I was after in the *dialog* manual page https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog. The closest seems to be the `--menu` and `--inputmenu` options. These would be a reasonably succinct way of implementing either of the suggested workarounds.